# bundle update: env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler

Just updated `rubygems-bundler` from 1.2.2 to **1.3.0**

Not sure, exactly, that this is the problem but now I'm getting these errors:

```
$ bundle update
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
$ bundle install
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

please open a bug here: https://github.com/mpapis/executable-hooks/issues

as a temporary fix try:

```
rvm @global do gem regenerate_binstubs
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

#### Update 1:

As a fix for https://github.com/mpapis/executable-hooks/issues/6 version `1.2.1` of `executable-hooks` was released - it should fix the problem.

#### Update 2:

Folowing issues https://github.com/mpapis/executable-hooks/issues/7 https://github.com/mpapis/executable-hooks/issues/8 and finall fix in version `1.2.3` of `executable-hooks`

Comment: That worked for me. Curious, how did you know that would solve the issue?

Comment: look at the link - I'm the author, I thought that was fixed during installation - but obviously not, there has to be a bug - I need to revisit the process

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command in the `Terminal` to refresh the `executable-hooks` to the latest version and fix the issue:

`sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I have `bundler`, not `rubygems-bundler`, and my `gem` doesn't recognise `regenerate_binstubs`.

`rvm all-gemsets do gem update bundler` installed bundler 1.7.11 and fixed it for me.

Comment: The bundler update works for me, too. I haven't installed the `executable-hooks` gem.