# /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks : No such file or directory

Tags: nginx, capistrano, raspberry-pi, thin

I'm trying to deploy to a Raspberry Pi using Capistrano 3.0 / Thin / NGINX I've got it working, but in my restart block I have

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute '/etc/init.d/thin restart'
      execute 'sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart'
    end
  end
end
```

To which I am greated with

```
 INFO [128fb9a3] Running /etc/init.d/thin restart on raspberrypi.local
DEBUG [128fb9a3] Command: /etc/init.d/thin restart
DEBUG [128fb9a3]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [128fb9a3]    ruby_executable_hooks
DEBUG [128fb9a3]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [128fb9a3]
```

I've tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936933/bundle-update-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory) but with no success.

The commands seem to work fine if I SSH into the PI and run them as root.

I should mention that I pretty much used this tutorial: http://creativepsyco.github.io/blog/2013/04/10/deploying-rails-on-nginx-and-thin/ to get things setup

Answer (score 6):

### Totally Hackish Solution

The gem `rvm1-capistrano3` didn't end up working for me, so i ended up just hard linking `ruby_executable_hooks` and `ruby` like so

```
$ ln -s `which ruby_executable_hooks` /usr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks
$ ln -s `which ruby` /usr/bin/ruby
```

**WARNING**, This assumes that ruby was installed with RVM, you might want to make sure you are not going to overwrite something by doing something like `ls -l /usr/bin | grep ruby`

**ALSO** I realize this is totally hackish and probably not the right thing to do on a production server, but it worked for me on my Raspberry-Pi...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried switching to system ruby?

```
rvm use system
```

Then install capistrano there. This would take your `rvm` issues out of play.

Answer (score 2):

The article you linked refers to the old version of Capistrano.

It looks like you are using rvm (the `ruby_executable_hooks` seems to be an RVM thing), in which case you'll need one of the Cap 3 compatible RVM adapters, find them at Github named `capistrano/rvm` (under the Capistrano account) or `rvm1-capistrano3`, which appears to be maintained by someone aligned with the rvm core team.