# How do I run bundle remotely when RVM is involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, ssh, rvm, bundler

I am trying to create a tiny shell script that will deploy a Rails app by first rsync'ing, then running the bundle command remotely via ssh. My shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_SERVER="myserver.com"
REMOTE_USER="me"
REMOTE_PATH="/home/me/"
BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/bundle"

# Step 1: Rsync
rsync -ave ssh --exclude-from '.ignore' ./ $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_SERVER:$REMOTE_PATH

# Step 2: Bundle
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_SERVER "cd $REMOTE_PATH && $BUNDLE_PATH install"
```

Rsync'ing works fine but when RVM is involved, the bundle line throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

So, I'm wondering ... **Is it possible to run the bundle (and other commands like rake) as part of a single ssh command?**

If it matters, the remote server is running Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Check this thread, maybe can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936933/bundle-update-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: My test server already has executable-hooks 1.2.6. Also, when I try the commands from that thread, I get permission denied errors. Do I need to run them as root?

Answer (score -1):

This problem has already been solved by the community. It's called Capistrano.

http://capistranorb.com/

Comment: No offense, but I downvoted you because your answer completely ignored my question. The project that prompted this question is, in fact, an exercise in trying to deploy an app WITHOUT a large tool like Capistrano (which, btw, I've been using since pre-version 1 so I'm quite familiar with it). With version 3, Capistrano bills itself as a "multi-server automation tool". Sometimes, I don't need that.