# running resources:compileSass in sbt produces an error: env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, scala, rubygems, sass

I am trying to run `resources:compileSass` from sbt (scala thing). It uses a script (sass) that has the following header line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
```

Here is the full output:

```
> resources:compileSass
[info] Compiling SASS files...
[error] env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last resources:compileSass for the full output.
[error] (resources:compileSass) SASS compilation failed with code 127.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 14, 2014 2:00:55 PM
> last resources:compileSass
java.lang.RuntimeException: SASS compilation failed with code 127.
    at com.openstudy.sbt.ResourceManagementPlugin$.doSassCompile(ResourceManagementPlugin.scala:170)
    at com.openstudy.sbt.ResourceManagementPlugin$$anonfun$25.apply(ResourceManagementPlugin.scala:330)
    at com.openstudy.sbt.ResourceManagementPlugin$$anonfun$25.apply(ResourceManagementPlugin.scala:330)
    at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:54)
    at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My environment is: Mac OS 10.9.2, ruby-2.1.2 that is managed by rvm (the system ruby is ruby 2.0.0p247). My ruby_executable_hooks is 1.3.2.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936933/bundle-update-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory), but it did not help. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading MacOS to 10.9.5. This allowed me to install compass and sass natively (to the system ruby) and run resources:compileSass in sbt.